# R: Order by Date (by Year, by Month)

Tags: r

I have dates in the format mm/yyyy in column 1, and then results in column 2.

1. month       Result
2. 01/2018    96.13636
3. 02/2018    96.40000
4. 3/2018     94.00000
5. 04/2018    97.92857
6. 05/2018    95.75000
7. 11/2017    98.66667
8. 12/2017    97.78947

How can I order by month such that it will start from the first month (11/2017) and end (05/2018).

I have tried a few 'orders', but none seem to be ordering by year and then by month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tidyverse (w/ lubridate added):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dfYrMon <- 
    df1 %>% 
    mutate(date = parse_date_time(month, "my"),
           year = year(date),
           month = month(date)
           ) %>% 
    arrange(year, month) %>% 
    select(date, year, month, result)
```

With data:

```
df1 <- tibble(month = c("01/2018", "02/2018", "03/2018", "04/2018", "05/2018", "11/2017", "12/2017"), 
              result = c(96.13636, 96.4, 94, 97.92857, 95.75, 98.66667, 97.78947))
```

Will get you this 'dataframe':

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 4
>         date  year month   result
>       <dttm> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
> 1 2017-11-01  2017    11 98.66667
> 2 2017-12-01  2017    12 97.78947
> 3 2018-01-01  2018     1 96.13636
> 4 2018-02-01  2018     2 96.40000
> 5 2018-03-01  2018     3 94.00000
> 6 2018-04-01  2018     4 97.92857
> 7 2018-05-01  2018     5 95.75000
> ```

Making your data values atomic (year in its own column, month in its own column) generally improves the ease of manipulation.

Or if you want to use base R date manipulations instead of *lubridate*'s:

```
library(tidyverse)

dfYrMon_base <- 
    df1 %>% 
    mutate(date = as.Date(paste("01/", month, sep = ""), "%d/%m/%Y"),
           year = format(as.Date(date, format="%d/%m/%Y"),"%Y"),
           month = format(as.Date(date, format="%d/%m/%Y"),"%m")
          ) %>%
    arrange(year, month) %>%
    select(date, year, month, result)

dfYrMon_base
```

Note the datatypes created.

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 4
>         date  year month   result
>       <date> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
> 1 2017-11-01  2017    11 98.66667
> 2 2017-12-01  2017    12 97.78947
> 3 2018-01-01  2018    01 96.13636
> 4 2018-02-01  2018    02 96.40000
> 5 2018-03-01  2018    03 94.00000
> 6 2018-04-01  2018    04 97.92857
> 7 2018-05-01  2018    05 95.75000
> ```

Answer (score 2):

We can convert it to `yearmon` class and then do the `order`

```
library(zoo)
out <- df1[order(as.yearmon(df1$month, "%m/%Y"), df1$Result),]
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#    month   Result
#1 11/2017 98.66667
#2 12/2017 97.78947
#3 01/2018 96.13636
#4 02/2018 96.40000
#5 03/2018 94.00000
#6 04/2018 97.92857
#7 05/2018 95.75000
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(month = c("01/2018", "02/2018", "03/2018", "04/2018", 
"05/2018", "11/2017", "12/2017"), Result = c(96.13636, 96.4, 
94, 97.92857, 95.75, 98.66667, 97.78947)), .Names = c("month", 
"Result"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: or perhaps `z <- read.zoo(df1, FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%m/%Y"); replace(df1, TRUE, fortify.zoo(z))`  (You can just use `z` and omit the second line if a zoo object is sufficient.)

Comment: Thanks!

Another q... plotting this now I get the error
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

I do not understand since x on y should be fine ...